# Drupal's "Rules" module -- syntax for using form fields

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to use the Rules module to send me an email via php with some information that's submitted in a Webform.  I've tried a number of different ways to get the submitted field into a variable so I can include it in $message but nothing's working.  Anyone know what I'm missing?

I've tried:

```
$message .= $data[components][honoree_name];
$message .= $data[components][honoree_name][0];
$message .= $data[submitted][honoree_name];
$message .= printr($data[components][honoree_name][0]);
```

And a bunch of other variations.  I can't seem to find any clear examples nor any step by step usage of Rules in this instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

(I am using Drupal 6, btw!)

Answer (score 0):

Was missing the "[value]" part:

```
$message .= '<pre>' . print_r($data[components][honoree_name][value][0], true) . '</pre>';
```

was what I was looking for!